# Why does this behaviour of Groovy nested quotes in a string occur

Tags: arrays, string, groovy, aws-cli, jenkins-groovy

I recently had to run an aws cli command via a Groovy function. It was a complex command looking roughly like:

```
aws dynamodb get-item --output text --table-name tableName \
 --key='{"partitopnKey":{"S":"partitionKeyValue"}}' --query "Item.[someOtherValue]"
```

This command, which works in the terminal, was supposed to be run in the Groovy pipeline like so:

```
String nameOfVar = "aws dynamodb get-item --output text --table-name tableName \
 --key='{"partitopnKey":{"S":"${partitionKeyValue}"}}' --query "Item.[someOtherValue]""
Process nameOfAnotherVar = nameOfVar.execute()
nameOfOtherVar.waitFor()
```

Obviously the quotes above are wrong, but there in lies the issue. I could not find any quote combination that could get it to run, and I have tried literally dozens. I have tried what I am almost certain properly escaped versions of a working query.

I've also tried replaceing `String` and `Process` with `def`. I have tried with the `=` for the `--key` assignment, as both work with the AWS CLI.

The solution that did work for me was simply setting `nameOfVar` to be:

```
def nameOfVar = ["aws", "dynamodb", "get-item", "--output", "text", "--table-name", "tableName" \
 "--key" "{\"partitopnKey\":{\"S\":\"${partitionKeyValue}\"}}", "--query", "Item.[someOtherValue]"]
```

My question is such: Why did the array of strings work and the string not work?

Comment: Your query quotes are not scaped properly. TRY THIS:
String nameOfVar = "aws dynamodb get-item --output text --table-name tableName \
 --key='{\"partitopnKey\":{\"S\":\"${partitionKeyValue}\"}}' --query \"Item.[someOtherValue]\""

Comment: @victorm, what you've suggested is impossible. If I use `'` instead of `"` it won't expand the variable `${partitionKeyValue}`. Using single quotes was one of the 1st things I've tried.

Comment: I’m not suggesting you use single quotes. I’m suggesting you scape the inner double quotes.